# How do I set the version of a DLL built in C, compiled with CL.EXE?

Tags: c, windows, dll, version, cl.exe

If I compile the source for a C-language DLL with CL.exe, how do I set the file properties including File version Product name, Product version, Copyright and so on, so that I can view these properties in Windows Explorer?

[image: version number]

In a .NET application written in C#, I could do this with assembly attributes like `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.4")]`.  How do I do this in a C-language project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Embed a VersionInfo resource into your dll/application.

http://codingmisadventures.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/embedding-version-in-your-application-using-visual-c/

[VERSIONINFO resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource)